# Change IP address, SubnetMask & Default Gateway using JAVA on linux, Using Bash Script is not an option

Tags: java, linux

So in my application user can get the machine's current IP Addressing Scheme and can change it as well.
This app can be deployed on both Windows/Linux OS, For Windows it's quite simple

```
String[] command = { "netsh", "interface", "ip", "set", "address", "name=", "Local Area Connection" ,"source=static", "addr=",ipAddress,"mask=", subnetMask, defaultGateway};
Process pp = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Unable to do it using the Linux commands which are normally used to change IP/SubnetMask/Gateway

```
"sudo ifconfig eth0 down; "
sudo ifconfig eth0 "+ipAddress+" netmask "+subnetMask+"; " 
sudo ifconfig eth0 up; " 
sudo route del default;" 
sudo route add default gw "+defaultGateway+"; " 
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart ;";
```

Any Idea what's the best way to change IP addressing using Java on Linux Platform